# 'NSRectEdge' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I have a custom view controller that loads objects from a XIB, one of which is an `NSPopover`.

I have a method on the view controller that essentially passes through to the popover, like so:

```
func showRelativeToRect(positioningRect: NSRect, ofView positioningView: NSView!, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge) {
    self.popover.showRelativeToRect(positioningRect, ofView: positioningView, preferredEdge: preferredEdge)
}
```

However, this causes a compilation error that I don't quite understand:

```
/Users/Craig/projects/.../EditItemPopoverController.swift:23:102: 'NSRectEdge' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
```

This seems to be caused by the conflicting available types of `NSRectEdge`, which is substantiated by the autocomplete:

[image]

**How** can I tell Swift that I would like to use a particular type? Diving into the `NSPopover.swift` class, it seems it is using the version:

`typealias NSRectEdge = Int`

But I don't know how to tell the Swift compiler, in my view controller, that *this* is the type I want to use. I'm able to workaround this issue by defining my method to take `Int` instead of `NSRectEdge`, but I'd like to use the same method signature as the popover.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it really didn't answer your question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be resolved in the most recent beta. (Or maybe Beta 6. All I know is that it works properly in Beta 7.)

Answer (score 1):

I tried compiling a test project with this code with:

```
typealias NSRectEdge = Int
```

at the top of the file, and it worked - perhaps just redeclaring it works.  This isn't documented anywhere though.

Really I think there should be a separate command such as `using` in c#, but that's not there yet.

Comment: Thanks - this workaround got me compiling until Apple sorted things out.